# How and Where to define this ImageView in xml?

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer, picasso

In this [Android Navigation Icon - Profile picture instead of hamburger icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45445646/android-navigation-icon-profile-picture-instead-of-hamburger-icon) stackoverfolw post

`ImageView profileImage = (ImageView) 
 binding.navView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.iv_profile_image);`

How an Where to define `R.id.iv_profile_image` in which xml file ?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the XML code in the example you linked. However, I noticed the following line in the Activity's onCreate() method. This would indicate that the XML file being used is called activity_maps.xml. Most likely this is where the ImageView was placed.

```
binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_maps);
```

Assuming this assumption is correct, the ImageView can be declared something like this. The answer to "where" within the XML depends as XML is a declarative language.

```
<ImageView  android:id="@+id/iv_profile_image"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            ...
            android:contentDescription="@string/to_replace" />
```

Comment: Ok . Then what is  `ActivityMapsBinding binding;` ? Is it a standard class ? I can't find it .

Comment: I don't think that is a standard class as I can't find any documentation on it. But it seems what you're concerned about is adding the ImageView to the toolbar correct? This can be done with the following, `((Toolbar) getSupportActionBar()).setNavigationIcon(YOUR_ICON);` where "YOUR_ICON" can be a drawable. In this case you wouldn't need to use ActivityMapsBinding.